# should we publish wopi host web application on server?

Tags: webapp2, ms-wopi

I have a sample code for wopi host and I have installed web app server on my server (192.168.1.103) and a site with name HTTP80 appeared under sites root in IIS manager. I want to know if I have to publish the wopi host into IIS in my server.
I have downloaded the wopi host sample code from [this site](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Building-an-Office-Web-f98650d6/view/Discussions#content).

How can I use this code to open my doc in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

1. Deploy the WopiHost project to your IIS
2. Replace `App_Data\Discovery.xml` with an XML you find at `http://192.168.1.103/hosting/discovery` (your OWA server)
3. Adjust `appWopiServer` in the web.config to match the app you deployed to the IIS
4. Use `LinkController` (`Controllers\Api\LinkController.cs`) or the underlying `WopiAppHelper` to generate editing links.
5. Or navigate to the landing page of the `WopiHost` web app to see an example

Make sure your OWA server can access your WopiHost app.

And if you are interested check out the MVC6 version of the WOPI host [here](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely,
The WOPI application should **NOT** run from Visual Studio because then it's address would be http://localhost:< portnumber >/ and due to this Office Online Server would not be able to contact it to fetch the document contents and you will see an error message in your document IFrame.

To avoid this you **must** host the application in IIS and make sure that it is accessible from the Office Online Server.